# How log off a session when logoff doesn´t work

Tags: windows-server-2008, logoff

I have a session that is blocked by app, but i can´t log off using logoff command or taskgr. Do you know how force to log off?

Thx in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to logoff, disconnect, or reset terminal server user in production environment](http://serverfault.com/questions/151144/unable-to-logoff-disconnect-or-reset-terminal-server-user-in-production-environ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Server 2008, the command should be:

```
shutdown /l /f
```

This should force all apps to close and logoff the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: just realized about the 'windows server tagg'.

On command (administrative) line try shutdown /r /f

And it will reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hanging application, you can also use pslist/pskill to try and kill the offending app to allow logout (can't post more than one hyperlink yet, you get the idea):

pslist:  http:  technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682
pskill:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683